# Manjaro linux error: Failed to start Remount Root and Kernel File Systems

Tags: automounting, root-filesystem, uuid

I am using Manjaro Linux with `5.7.9-1-MANJARO` kernel. The system boots, but with an error
`Failed to start Remount Root and Kernel File Systems`. I took a look at the [`Manjaro` Forums](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/solved-manjaro-failed-to-start-remount-root-and-kernel-file-system/83395/8) as well as the question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/822887/boot-failed-failed-to-start-remount-root-and-kernel-file-systems) on `askubuntu`. Both suggest pretty much the same solution to the problem: correct the UUIDs. This would have been fine, had my problem been the same. But it appears that I am having correct UUIDs in my fstab.

---

/etc/fstab:

```
# /dev/sda2
UUID=71126187-20e1-4a92-a3d1-c5a71b06680a   /           ext4        rw,noatime,nodelalloc,data=writeback    0 0

# /dev/sda3
UUID=86d64f64-fb05-41c2-abd4-2f7f698a6b70   /home       ext4        rw,noatime  0 0

# /dev/sda1
UUID=6864-F1CB          /boot/efi   vfat        rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro   0 0

# /dev/sda4
UUID=9b8acffc-5cc9-43fc-98c0-27c9e8716d86   none        swap        defaults,pri=-2 0 0
```

---

sudo blkid:

```
/dev/nvme0n1p1: LABEL="WINDOWS EFI" UUID="9A8E-E384" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI system partition" PARTUUID="0f84d38b-3466-4076-9db7-e3027f78271f"
/dev/nvme0n1p2: PARTLABEL="Microsoft reserved partition" PARTUUID="bd2f56b5-ee7e-47b8-a2e2-b631a2b12f96"
/dev/nvme0n1p3: LABEL="Windows" BLOCK_SIZE="512" UUID="32566CB5566C7C0B" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="2982626d-ba52-4080-a3de-9aba273c06d1"
/dev/nvme0n1p4: BLOCK_SIZE="512" UUID="807C00447C003804" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="f1bb9b23-726a-46be-8e63-853c35763ba5"
/dev/nvme0n1p5: LABEL="Windows RE tools" BLOCK_SIZE="512" UUID="78B85430B853EAE0" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="c470bed2-96de-4701-90e1-7ad703c597b6"
/dev/sda1: UUID="6864-F1CB" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="c847197a-6d98-45df-9f40-607423e0c083"
/dev/sda2: UUID="71126187-20e1-4a92-a3d1-c5a71b06680a" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="b829b40a-495b-4788-a6f8-7b39a49c40e4"
/dev/sda3: UUID="86d64f64-fb05-41c2-abd4-2f7f698a6b70" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="db88ffde-d83b-4c46-9227-b2960cf4bf0a"
/dev/sda4: UUID="9b8acffc-5cc9-43fc-98c0-27c9e8716d86" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="51070783-cd6b-4cc8-9e0c-6951d49beb6b"
/dev/sda5: LABEL="New Volume" BLOCK_SIZE="512" UUID="F2220740220708F5" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="21ef0b4b-f298-47c6-9cdc-70eca0cc4cb8"
```

---

lsblk -f:

```
NAME        FSTYPE FSVER LABEL            UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINT
sda                                                                                           
├─sda1      vfat   FAT32                  6864-F1CB                            1021.7M     0% /boot/efi
├─sda2      ext4   1.0                    71126187-20e1-4a92-a3d1-c5a71b06680a     81G    12% /
├─sda3      ext4   1.0                    86d64f64-fb05-41c2-abd4-2f7f698a6b70  137.1G     1% /home
├─sda4      swap   1                      9b8acffc-5cc9-43fc-98c0-27c9e8716d86                [SWAP]
└─sda5      ntfs         New Volume       F2220740220708F5                                    
nvme0n1                                                                                       
├─nvme0n1p1 vfat   FAT32 WINDOWS EFI      9A8E-E384                                           
├─nvme0n1p2                                                                                   
├─nvme0n1p3 ntfs         Windows          32566CB5566C7C0B                                    
├─nvme0n1p4 ntfs                          807C00447C003804                                    
└─nvme0n1p5 ntfs         Windows RE tools 78B85430B853EAE0
```

What is causing the issue and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I  guess you can boot into the recovery console? Try running `e2fsck` ([man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/e2fsck)) on it, e.g.:

```
e2fsck -f -v -C 0 -t /dev/sda2
```

If it doesn't help, please check your GRUB command line.

---

**Edit**: the issue was actually caused by dubious *default* mount options:

```
rw,noatime,nodelalloc,data=writeback
```

I've recommended to reduce them down to

```
defaults,noatime
```

which has solved the issue the OP was having.